# I need to extract names from a list and paste them into a different sequence (auto-typer)

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I am thinking something like this will extract names from a list

```
String [] myArray ;
    if (stringArrayList.size()>0){
        Iterator<String [] > i = stringArrayList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
                  myArray =  i.next();
                  for(String s : myArray)
                      System.out.println(s);
                }
                }

        }
```

But I can't figure out how to put each string into a different sequence that would look like this:

`Auto-Type: @"string1"{ENTER}{SPACE}"string2"{ENTER}{SPACE}` ... and so on

string1 = name1

string2 = name2

Comment: you have an array and you are searching a method do print randomly the contained strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through the array normally. Something like:

```
Iterator<String[]> iter = stringArrayList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  String[] arr = iter.next();
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("string" + i + " = " + arr[i]);
  }
}
```